# Allow only one of specific value in Ruby array

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to allow only one of a specific value in an array?

For example, I would like to allow only one value of `cat` in the following array:

```
["dog", "cat", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]
```

such that it returned:

```
["dog", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]
```

EDIT: Apologies for not making this clear enough, I am not looking for uniq! I want to ensure that there is only 1 of a *specified* value.

Comment: Try with [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#uniq-method)

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to remove only duplicated `"cat"`, or any duplicates?

Comment: This is interesting. On second reading, I think the question is perfectly clear. Yet on first reading I was one of at least five readers who thought `uniq` was called for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To make only one value unique:**

```
a = ["dog", "cat", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]

(a.count("cat") - 1).times { a.delete_at(a.index("cat"))}

#=> ["dog", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]
```

This preserves the order of the elements in the array.

**To delete consecutive items:**

Use `Enumerable#chunk`:

```
a = ["dog", "cat", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]

a.chunk(&:itself).map(&:first)

#=> ["dog", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]
```

Note that in Ruby < 2.2 you have to use `chunk{|w| w}` because `itself` isn't defined.

Comment: Nice and clean solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to modify the array in place:

```
def keep_one(arr, obj)
  i = arr.each_index.find { |i| arr[i] == obj }
  if i
    arr.delete(obj)
    arr.insert(i,obj)
  end
end

arr = ["dog", "cat", "cat", 7.2, { a: 3}, "cat", "dog"]

a = arr.dup
keep_one(a,"cat")
a #=> ["dog", "cat", 7.2, {:a=>3}, "dog"] 

a = arr.dup
keep_one(a,"dog")
a #=> ["dog", "cat", "cat", 7.2, {:a=>3}, "cat"] 

a = arr.dup
keep_one(a,7.2)
a #=> ["dog", "cat", "cat", 7.2, {:a=>3}, "cat", "dog"] 

a = arr.dup
keep_one(a,"pig")
a #=> ["dog", "cat", "cat", 7.2, {:a=>3}, "cat", "dog"]
```

If you do not wish to modify `arr`:

```
keep_one(arr.dup,"cat")
  #=> ["dog", "cat", 7.2, {:a=>3}, "dog"] 
arr
  #=> ["dog", "cat", "cat", 7.2, {:a=>3}, "dog"]
```

or

```
def keep_one(arr, obj)
  found = false
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |o,a|
    a << o unless o == obj && found
    found = true if o == obj
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order of elements does not matter:

```
unique_element = "cat"
animals = ["dog", "cat", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]
animals << animals.delete(unique_element) if animals.include?(unique_element)

p animals
#=> ["dog", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog", "cat"]
```

Or, to keep it in the index of the first instance:

```
unique_element = "cat"
animals = ["dog", "cat", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]
if animals.include?(unique_element)
  index_position = animals.index(unique_element)
  animals.insert(index_position, animals.delete(unique_element))
end

p animals
#=> ["dog", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]
```

Comment: It took me a minute to understand what was going on in #1. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a method that can remove duplicates:

```
require 'set'

list = ["dog", "cat", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]

def limit(list, *entries)
  # Create a tracking table for terms that are limited
  entries = Hash[entries.to_a.flatten.collect { |i| [ i, 0 ] }]

  list.select do |i|
    case (entries[i])
    when 0
      entries[i] += 1
      i
    when nil
      i
    end
  end
end

puts limit(list, 'cat').inspect
# => ["dog", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]
```

You could also roll this into a fancy subclass of Array that limits this for you, but there's a lot of hooks you'll have to add as elements can be added a variety of ways.

Comment: Ah, limited to one instance of *one* value. I'll adjust.

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for :) Based on the question and I/O example, `#uniq` is the answer. Good day

Comment: This seems like an impulse answer. The question did not specify his intentions greatly enough for this to be an acceptable solution.

Comment: @radubogdan This handles the requirements where *only* `cat` is limited in the array. Note the duplicate `dog` values.

Comment: @IronSavior Everyone's missing the key here: Duplicate values **are** allowed, except for one value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def remove_duplicates(arr, value)
  index = arr.index(value)
  index ? (arr - [value]).insert(index, value) : arr
end
```

Results:

```
irb(main):018:0> remove_duplicates(["dog", "cat", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"], "cat")
=> ["dog", "cat", "hamster", "rabbit", "dog"]                                                                                                                                                   
irb(main):019:0> remove_duplicates([1, 1, 2, 2, 3], "cat")                                                                                                    
=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
irb(main):020:0> remove_duplicates([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1], 2)
=> [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```